# unique value with custom request laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, validation

i have custom request in laravel ..
this is the code

```
 public function rules()
{
    if($this->ajax())
    {
        return [];
    }
    else
    {
        return 
        [
            'username'=> 'required|min:3|max:30|unique:users',
            'password'=> 'required|min:6',
            'email'=>'required|min:3|max:35|unique:users',
            'permission'=>'required',
            'phone'=>'required',
            'division'=>'required',
        ];          
    }

}
```

and i need to to ignore the current id from validation 
i tried this

```
    public function rules()
{
    if($this->ajax())
    {
        return [];
    }
    else
    {
        return 
        [
            'username'=> 'required|min:3|max:30|unique:users,id'.$this->id,
            'password'=> 'required|min:6',
            'email'=>'required|min:3|max:35|unique:users',
            'permission'=>'required',
            'phone'=>'required',
            'division'=>'required',
        ];          
    }

}
```

but its ignoring the whole user name from validation not just the current id ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `auth()->user()->id` instead of `$this->id` to get current user's ID.

Also, I'm not sure about the syntax you're using when trying to add ignoring ID. From [`unique()` rule docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique):

> To instruct the validator to ignore the user's ID, we'll use the Rule class to fluently define the rule. In this example, we'll also specify the validation rules as an array instead of using the | character to delimit the rules:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

Comment: alexey im not login yet so auth will not work also what if i need to do it with ather table like colors department what ever how could i let it ignore the id come from the request thanks

Comment: If user is not logged in, what user ID are you planning to use during validation?

Comment: its custom request named as     public function update(UsersRequest $request,$id) its will work if i used the normal Request but i need to put the validation in sparated request like UsersRequest